# Not compile time constant

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have:

```
    static const std::array<std::pair<ServerD, unsigned int>, 4> dataSizes =
{ std::make_pair(ServerD::ContentType, 1)
, std::make_pair(ServerD::RemoteAddress, 2)
, std::make_pair(ServerD::RemoteUser, 3)
, std::make_pair(ServerD::Url, 4)
};

template <unsigned int Index>
struct SizeFinder {
    static const unsigned int SizeFor(ServerD data) {
        return (dataSizes[Index].first == data) ? dataSizes[Index].second :
            SizeFinder<Index - 1>::SizeFor(data);
    }
};

template <>
struct SizeFinder<0> {
    static const unsigned int SizeFor(ServerD data) {
        return (dataSizes[0].first == data) ? dataSizes[0].second :
            0;
    }
};
```

Why is this not a compile time constant:

```
char tst[SizeFinder<4>::SizeFor(serverD)]
```

// Error    1   error C2975: 'BufferSize' : invalid template argument for 'isapi::`anonymous-namespace'::GetVariableFor', **expected compile-time constant** expression

I must make this work without constexpr. VS2013 still does not have this.

**EDIT** As it seems static const functions cannot compute at compile time, is there a workaround for C++ 03 ?

Comment: it has to be a static const var not a function, and what's the point of tagging it c++11 if you can't use constexpr

Comment: @aaronman Fixed that. I need some way there to transmit ServerD.

Comment: `dataSizes` has memory that is initialized at runtime, you can't access it at compile time. @aaronman I don't think `constexpr` would help.

Comment: the workaround is not to use an automatic array

Comment: @uk4321 what to use then ?

Comment: the other kind (dynamic arrays i.e. `std::vector`)

Comment: @uk4321 I need compile time access to the second member. No dyn arrays

Comment: @uk4321 make_pair code -> second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you simply need a compile-time mapping from `ServerD` to `unsigned int`. Why not  embed it in the enumeration values:

```
enum class ServerD : unsigned int {
    ContentType = 1U,
    RemoteAddress = 2U,
    RemoteUser = 3U,
    Url = 4U
};

char tst[ServerD::Url];
```

Comment: Wow. It started in a strange way all this. But your answer is very accurate.

Comment: Still interested if something along the lines presented is doable though

Comment: This doesn't really map anything to anything (except names to values). If he needs the `ServerD` values for something else then this won't work.

Comment: @uk4321 Yes, it only does what the OP wants: map enumerators to unsigned integers.